# Implementing Revolution Slider

Tags: entrymodel

The slider requires an unique ID per slide, wrapped in `<li>` tags, so I am trying this:

```
<div id="rev_slider_15_1" class="rev_slider fullwidthabanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.2.5.4">
<ul>

    <!-- SLIDES -->

    {% for testimonials in craft.entries.section('testimonials').limit(3) %} 

    <li data-index="rs-{{ testimonials.id }}" >

        <!-- LAYERS -->

        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->

        <p class="tp-caption tp-resizeme" 
           id="slide-{{ testimonials.id }}-layer-2">

            {{ testimonials.body_testimonial }}

        </p>

        <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->

        <span class="tp-caption tp-resizeme author" 
              id="slide-{{ testimonials.id }}-layer-3" >

            {{ testimonials.title }}

        </span>

    </li>

    {% endfor %}    

</ul>
</div>
```

This results in the first slide entry with both Title & Body, but the second and third slides only parse the Title not the Body.

Could someone verify the craft code is correct? The entries are made in a Channel section with a handle; testimonials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code looks fine.

It's possible that the second and third entries just don't have content in the `body_testimonial` field.

*(Unrelated — I recommend using `testimonial` as your loop variable, since it represents a single Testimonial entry. This is a good practice in general: Variables that represent a list should have a plural name, and variables that represent a single object should have a singular name.)*

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's embarrassing but during the cause of learning I would have wiped the entry body. Working fine now and appreciate pointing out the valid argument to use singular grammar.